# 3 Layer Rails Models, Pulling My Hair Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is only my third rails app and up until now they've been pretty simple. All I've been trying to do is make something where a 'user' can add multiple 'manufacturers', and each of those manufacturers can have multiple 'lines'. The ultimate goal is to be able to find a user's lines, a user's manufacturers, etc. I'm getting a "Couldn't find Manufacturer without an ID" error on my controller.

I want users to be able to add manufacturers, then add new lines off each manufacturer. Here are my files, I'm having a hard time and I know it's probably something dumb. I'm not trying to use nested forms yet, just trying to get the relationships down first.

routes.rb:

```
  resources :manufacturers do
    resources :lines
  end

  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"

  get "about" => "pages#about"

  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', :via => "get"
  match '/users', :to => 'users#index', :as => "all_users", :via => "get"
  match '/users/:name' => 'users#show', via: :get, as: :public_profile
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :manufacturers
end
```

manufacturer.rb

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lines
end
```

line.rb

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

lines_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:id])
    @line = @manufacturer.lines.build
  end
```

Please let me know if there are any other files that you'd need. I really just want the _form for lines to pull the manufacturer_id into its basic scaffold form... I think I'd know what to do from there.

UPDATE:

app/views/lines/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@manufacturer,@line) do |f| %>
  <% if @line.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@line.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this line from being     saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @line.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :manufacturer_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :manufacturer_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the route setup, your `new` action is executed for `/manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/new`.  So for this URI pattern, your `LinesController#new` should be as:

```
# app/controllers/lines_controller.rb
def new
  @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
  @line = @manufacturer.lines.build
end
```

The change is to use `params[:manufacturer_id]` instead of `params[:id]`.

Comment: Now I'm getting an 'undefined method lines_path', referencing this:  <%= form_for(@line) do |f| %>

Comment: can't write unknown attribute `html'

Comment: I think you're confused with how nested routes work.  With what you've shown, there won't be `lines_path`, there will be `manufacturer_line_path`.  I see @Vitalyp commented as I'm typing this, please give that a try.  Also to see what routes are available, run `rake routes` from the console.

Comment: That's what I was calling to: <%= link_to 'Add new Line', new_manufacturer_line_path(@manufacturer) %>

Comment: new_manufacturer_line GET    /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/new(.:format)      lines#new

Comment: Please add your form code in your question, it's difficult without seeing it.  Also what errors are you getting after the suggested changes?

Comment: In lines/new.html.erb use form_for(@manufacturer,@line) instead of form_for(@line) like Vitalyp suggested.

Comment: I did that, and I posted my lines/_form.html.erb